# Integration with mathematica?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, evaluation

I am very new to Mathematica. I am trying to evaluate

```
∫ (1+lnx)Sqrt(1+(xlnx)^2)
```

using Mathematica. I know a substitution must be done so I have set

```
u = xln(x), du = (1+ln(x))dx.
```

What I don't understand is how to properly use the U-sub in Mathematica to get the correct integral. Please help? Again, I am extremely new to Mathematica so any advice needs to be exact to I can understand how to input it into the program correctly. Any useful input is appreciated.

Comment: As somebody already told you in an answer to your previous question,please read at least this first: Language Overview:  http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/LanguageOverview.html
and Wolfram Language Syntax:  http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Syntax.html

Comment: Also, welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Or go here to see examples that are very close to the integral you want to perform: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate.html As you can see, there is no need to explicitly tell Mathematica what substitutions to make.

Comment: This is an example where it is far easier to do the substitution by hand and feed the`Integral` in terms of `u` to mathematica.

Comment: Mathematica uses square brackets for functions. ln(x) ==> Log[x]

Answer (score 5):

Normally in Mathematica, you just need to type the integral and it will evaluate without needing to specify a substitution or anything. Unfortunately Mathematica does not know how to do this integral.

I agree with what george2079 said in the comments:

> This is an example where it is far easier to do the substitution by hand and feed the integral in terms of u to mathematica.

I have a piece of u-sub code I've written that I will paste below. You say you're very new to Mathematica, so you might not understand some of the lines. I didn't write this code for this question, I'm just pasting something I already have and use form time to time in situations like these.

```
USub[integrand_, x_, z_ == f_] := Module[{inverse, Dinv, new, int},

    inverse = Normal[First[x /. Quiet[Solve[z == f, x]]]];
    Dinv = Simplify[D[inverse, z]];

    new = FullSimplify[integrand Dinv /. {f -> z, x -> inverse}, z > 0];

    int = Integrate[new, z];

    Print["If ", z == f, ", then ", \[DifferentialD]z == HoldForm[# \[DifferentialD]x]&[D[f, x]], ", ", x == inverse, ", and ", \[DifferentialD]x == HoldForm[# \[DifferentialD]z]&[Dinv], "."];
    Print["Make this substitution:"];

    Print[
        HoldForm[Equal[
            Integrate[integrand, x],
            Integrate[#1, #2],
            #3,
            #4
        ]]&[new, z, int, int /. z -> f]
    ]

]
```

Here's your example:

```
USub[(1 + Log[x])*Sqrt[1 + (x*Log[x])^2], x, u == x Log[x]]
```

[image]